# Cannot open qbittorent via terminal by typing in the name

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, software-installation

Whenever I try to open any application via terminal. For Example; If I try qbittorent;

```
$ qbittorent

Command 'qbittorent' not found, did you mean:

  command 'qbittorrent' from deb qbittorrent (4.1.7-1ubuntu3)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

I already have qbittorent installed. Does anyone know how to open it?

edit:

Output of: `$ echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Output of: `dpkg -L qbittorent | grep bin`

```
dpkg-query: package 'qbittorent' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
```

I don't know why it says qbittorent is not installed but I can open it directly from Activities panel.

Comment: Is the issue only for qbittorrent?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu or is this Ubuntu under Windows?

Comment: On first sight this looks like a problem with your `$PATH`. Edit your question and mention the output of `echo $PATH` and `dpkg -L qbittorent | grep bin`

Comment: It currently only occurs with qbittorent and I'm currently on dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is called `qbittorrent` not `qbittorent` ( `r` is missing).

Comment: `qbit` + TAB should give the correct, full name.

Comment: Damn! I cannot believe I missed it for the entire time. Anyway thanks man!

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thanks man! That's a new info.

Comment: @ArjunKShibu TAB completion was originally just for file and command names.  A lot of completions have been added for bash so it works even more places.  You may want to pick up a good Linux command line tutorial or book.

Answer (score 0):

The proper name to use is `qbittorrent-arnatious.qbittorrent`.

You can type a new letters and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to find it again if it changes in future.

e.g. `qbit` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>